# Configuration management in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, configuration, configuration-management

i guess this is a hard one (for me): we have requirements for a .net (web)project which should be used with differnent configurations for different customers.

Example: Cusomer A wants a compiled Version which includes a big part of the MainApplication but with some code excluded and two separate assemblies. Customer B wants the whole MainApplication with other assemblies and for example a different gui.

I did a smal research and concluded with the following settings:

- Using the configuration manager of VisualStudio for leading to different "builds", then
- building the project (including several configurations) and deploying it by using NAnt
- Excluding code or using different code with complie directives

We never did this before so i have some questions:

1. is it possible to solve this with compile directives? (i can imagine that this point can grow very high complexity)
2. are there better ways to fit this project (with .net)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest building a plugin system/architecture - assemblies can be loaded dynamically on-demand, based on configuration entries.  You might need to write a separate tool to package up for deployment (i.e. including different assemblies in the bin folder), though.

Comment: Yes, we planed a "high plugin" usage architecture. But we also want to keep the code compileable in different Configurations/Solutions. How is this possible?

Comment: Configuration Manager is definitely a good way to go.  You could also look at config transforms (e.g. you can get Web.config.debug, Web.config.release, Web.config.CustomerX) - when you build for 'CustomerX', the changes in Web.config.CustomerX would be applied to the config file.  That should help? :)

Comment: Unfortunately we are using VS2008. Therefore we cant use config transforms. I guess NAnt is serving the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create different solutions? They would share some assemblies and have some assemblies unique to solution.

You can have multiple server builds configured for each of these solutions in your TFS so it's easy to get a build of any configuration while still commiting to one source control. Same goes for any other build system you work with.

Comment: Good approach. Can i use compile directives to share some code and exclude some code? I also can imagine that switching to another solution may be slow..

Comment: @elCapitano: you can, but if it's a lot of code my suggestion would be to refactor it into different assemblies somehow so it's as simple as including/not including them in solution. Otherwise it gets messy really, really fast

Comment: @elCapitano: what do you mean by switching to another solution?

Comment: My aim is switching from different solutions (with different code, sharing a lot of code) to one high configureable, pluginable solution

Comment: Using different solutions contains the possibility that the code-changes wont event compile in the other project when you share the code between several solutions.

Comment: @elCapitano: and if it happens, you will know right away because you use regular server builds, right?